# Set a default reviewer

Tags: github

I do pull requests in a repo where it's always the same person reviewing.
I would like to set him as the default reviewer so that I don't always have to choose him at each pull request, it'd be automatic.
How to do that ?

Comment: Not aware of the marking a default Reviewer. But if tagging a default person can work in your PR that is feasible.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

GitHub has the ability to set the default reviewer using a [`CODEOWNERS`](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/) file.

> Code owners are automatically requested for review when someone opens a pull request that modifies code that they own. When someone with admin permissions has [enabled required reviews](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/), they can optionally require approval from a code owner.
>
> To use a CODEOWNERS file, create a new file called CODEOWNERS in the root, `docs/`, or `.github/` directory of the repository, in the branch where you'd like to add the code owners.

Comment: I tried this on GitHub Enterprise Server 2.18.4 and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It looks like it should be supported- https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners. Their support should be able to help

Comment: Correct link for [CODEOWNERS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) info

Comment: And why I set, when I can't a code owner, but um default, with on all time need review, type a new dev on the team, I'd like if here review for understand more, but on all time I need set with is review.

Answer (score 46):

You should add `.github/CODEOWNERS` file with users to send PR to.

Example to send PR for any change on codebase represented by `*`:

```
## code changes will send PR to following users
* @option1-user1 @option1-user2 @option2-your-org/team-name
```

See: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners

Note: `.github/CODEOWNERS` should be in `main` branch to be effective.

Comment: The same answer was given 4 years ago...

Comment: @Cjmarkham True, but this answer offers better details and is more to the point. The current accepted answer is just a huge block quote.

Comment: Worked for me. However, not on intermediate branches such as `develop`, `uat`